# Как обновить прошивку для LENOVO Legion 5-15ARH05, если у меня Linux

Tags: bios

У меня стоит Archlilux на Legion 5 Lenovo.
На сайте леново (https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ru/ru/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-5-15arh05/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS) увидел критическое обновление биоса и решил, что мне нужно обновиться.
Но на сайте LENOVO есть только установочный файл для windows 10.
Как обновиться в этом случае.

Comment: Сейчас занимаюсь созданием usb windows to go на компьютере с windows, попробую через windows to go запустить обновление для bios. Отпишусь как получу результат.

Comment: Если комп работает, если ни что плохого не происходит то не надо лезть и обновлять то что на дух не надо

Comment: получилось. вроде ничего не поломал )

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-lenovo-bios-from-linux-usb-stick-pen/

Answer (score -1):

Найти комп с виндой.
Скачать виндус 10.
С помощью rufus (https://rufus.ie/ru/) сделать windows to go.
Запустить винду со флешки.
Скачать прошивку.
Установить.
ВАЖНО!!! не вырубать комп !!!